# Bind the visibility of a TemplateField to the content of a BoundField

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, webforms

The (pseudo code) expression within the "Visible"-Tag of the TemplateField is what I like to achieve, any ideas?
I´d really love to do it declaratively. No OnRowCreated event handling, Cells[x], ...

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MyProperty" HeaderText="My Property" />
                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="<%# MyProperty == 'VisibleString' %>">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same applies to BoundFields too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not possible to do that on the TemplateField column itself because it has no DataBinding support. I had to do it within the ImageButton. Now it works perfectly:

```
<asp:ImageButton Visible='<%# Eval("MyProperty") == "VisibleString" %>' [...] />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only hide the content (Image in your case) but not the column, and with this the column header. It will display empty rows.